# Best structure other than Datatable to store ~half-a-million records in Frontend

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, datatable, binary

I have a Datatable which is fetching ~5,50,000 records from database(SQLite). When fetching it is slowing down the system.

I am storing these records on backend in SQLite Database and in frontend in Datatable.
Now what should i do so that database creation time(~10.5 hours) in backend and fetching time in Front end reduces.

Is there any other structure that can be used to do so. I have read that Dictionary & Binary File is fast. Can they be used for this purpose & how?

(Its not a web app. its a WPF desktop app where frontend and backend are on same machine).

Comment: I'd guess that depends (a) on the datastructure itself - is it just records or are there interdependencies and (b) on the calculations. Can the calculation be done with only one record or do you need reference to other records - if so, which?

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon Let us for a moment remove the aspect of calculations. Now what alternatives do we have other than Datatable? Why i am asking this is because to make such database with so many records my system takes approx 10.5 hours. If i could replace that database with bin file my both storing and fetching time will reduce.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: If it's taking 10.5 hours to *fetch* the data, then I doubt that it's the `DataTable` that's causing the problem.

Comment: Have you thought about doing the calcuation at the location of the data, rather than fetching it?

Comment: @JonSkeet 10.5 hours is the time taken to create such a database(SQLite) in backend.

Comment: First I do believe that Jon is right (as usual...). Generally, I would not build a DataTable if I can process the single records. I would either use LINQ or handcode the DB-Access.

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon: So the creation time has nothing to do with the DataTable? Separate your two problems.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: so you create *every time* a new Sqlite database "from stratch" ?

Comment: @Tigran: Yep but that process is not in user hand. Its in admin hand and admin only does so once a while

Comment: You don't provide enough information about the data and how it's created to give us any idea how to optimize your process. How is the data created? Is the bottleneck writing to the database, or the calculations required to create the records that are written? Without more context, all we can do is speculate.

Comment: How big is a single record? Can you estimate the total memory required to hold all that data at the same time in memory? How much ram has your system? Perhaps, if you don't want to change your requirements then the only other option is a faster and bigger hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem, *I believe*, is not the strucutre that you want to maintain but the *way* you manage your data-flow. Instead of fetching all data from database into some strcuture (`DataTable` in your case), make some `stored procedure` to make a calculations you need on *server-side* and return to you  data already calculated. In this way you gain several benefits, like:

- servers holding database servers are *usually* faster then development or client machine
- huge reduction of data trasmission, as you return *only result* of the calculation

**EDIT**

Considering edited post, I would say that `DataTable` is already highly optimized on in memory  access, and I don't think changing it to something else will bring you a notable benefits. What I think *can* bring a banefit is a revision of a program flow. In other words, try to answer following questions:

- do I need all that records *contemporary*  ?
- can I run some calculations in `service`, let's say, on night  ?
- can I use `SQL Server Express` (just example) and gain benefits of possibility to run a `stored procedure`, that *may* (have to be measured) run the stuff faster, even on the same machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about doing the calcuation at the location of the data, rather than fetching it? Can you give us some more information as what it's stored in and how you are fetching it and how you are processing it please.

It's hard to make a determination for a optimsation without the metrics and the background information.

It's easy to say - yes put the data in a file. But is the file local, is the network the problem, are you make best use of cores/threading etc.

Much better to start back from the data and see what needs to be done to it and then engineer the best optimisation.

Edit:

Ok so you are on the same machine? One thing you should really consider in this scenario is what are you doing to the data. Does it need to be SQL? If you are just using is to load a datatable? Or is a complexity you are not disclosing?

I've had a similar task- I just created a large text file and used memory mapping to read is efficicently without any overhead. Is this the kind of thing you're talking about?

Comment: Backend and frontend both are on same machine as its a WPF Desktop App.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [persisted dictionary like RaptorDB](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375413/RaptorDB-the-Document-Store) for storing and fetching/manipulating the data in an ArrayList. The proof of concept should not take long to build.